# any one can see code for symbian

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi I am developing an application in phonegap. For symbian platform we create .zip file of www folder and then change its extension to .wgz because of this any one can see actual code of js and html file by extracting .wgz folder. Then what is security? How to restrict user from seeing actual code? Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML engine running the app needs to see the HTML and JS anyway, so there's no way to make it completely invisible. However, you can obfuscate it so that it's unreadable to humans. See this QA:

[How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)